# HP 2000 keyboard issue

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard

I have a HP 2000 laptop running Windows-7 home basic. I know for sure nothing has been spilled on the keyboard.
The laptop boots up to the Windows login page. I cant login to the laptop because the "h" key doesnt work. The backspace key doesnt work either.  ok..so far looks like a keyboard hardware issue.
I restart the laptop, get windows to boot into the safe mode. This time I am able to login to windows and test all the keys in notepad. Everything seems ok. I then ran a CCleaner to delete the temp files and other such junk
Rebooted windows in normal mode, everything works fine, things seem all rosy again.
After a few more reboots, same issue pops up again.
My service center suggests to reinstall windows. I am ok with this, but dont like this solution without an explanation.
Does anyone have a suggestion on what could be causing this

Comment: Did you checked your start up folder, installed programs, Task manager for any  such weird application/process running?

Comment: The keyboards on laptops are generally pretty cheap, and overuse of a certain key may make it unreliable, or perhaps there is dust or some kind of insulator stuck under the key. I have seen plenty of keyboard failures, some are related to the connection to the motherboard or its cabling, and some are the keys and internal wiring. If it happens again, check with an external keyboard to make sure it is not at the operating system layer.

Answer (score 1):

What strange behaviour.

My first inclination was a mechanical failure, some dirt, or even broken keyboard membrane could cause intermittent issues like that.  Most keyboards it's pretty easy top pop the keys off, I would recommend taking a few off and just seeing if anything is unexpected under there.  Maybe it's dirty, maybe it got left in the sun, is warped, or cracking etc.

My second thought was he's got some virus that's altering, or preventing certain keystrokes.  The fact that they work in Safe mode but not in normal mode points me to this conclusion.  Wiping Windows is the sure fire way to remove bad software but it might not be completely necessary.  Try some antivirus programs, or virus detection software and see if it comes up with anything.

I also think that the suggestion from Richie Frame of checking the problem with an external keyboard is a great idea.

Comment: Would viruses come into the picture before logging in to windows?

Comment: Absolutely, if they are nasty enough they can show up before logging in.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Answer (score 1):

Boot your laptop from live Linux CD (Ubuntu for example) and test the keyboard in there. If all keys works fine in Ubuntu but not in Windows, probably this is software relate issue. Could be some kind of virus. Backup data and reinstall OS.

If you see the same problem in Ubuntu, this is hardware related failure. Most likely just a bad keyboard. Could be a faulty controller on the motherboard, but no likely.
If that's the case, replace the keyboard. It's only $15 on eBay.

Follow steps 8-15 in this HP 2000 disassembly guide to replace the keyboard.

http://www.insidemylaptop.com/hp-2000-laptop-disassembly/

Comment: Can you summarize the steps in that link, so that if the link goes dead, your answer is still useful?